# How to work with Bluetooth with Many Activities in Android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

i am creating an app in which from many activity we send and receive data through Bluetooth ,
so if i release socket in 1 activity ,so in other activity i have to connect that socket again
,so some time it is connect and sometime it disconnect , so how can i create only 1 socket and share to all over app?i have already tried to make 1 conman class to share but that also did't worked out.

Answer (score 0):

the right way to maintain Bluetooth connection between different activities, and in general - to share any Object across the entire application, is by using a `Service` class.

android `Service` derived class is the facility for your app to perform operations, and hold references to objects that needs to maintain it state regardless if any Activity changed, or even when there is no any Activity at all (when your app is in background)

you can bind the current foreground activity to a Service, and by that - to communicate with it from the current activity.

for more info - read: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

you'll find tones of tutorials and samples by searching on android Service, and binding to a Service...

I guess that for someone who not familiar with android Service - it would look a little complex and hard to understand ant implement, but eventually it's one of the most important component of the API's,   so it worth the effort.